# Public readonly field v.s. get-only property

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

Are there cases when you would want a public readonly field v.s. a get-only auto-implemented property?

```
public class Foo
{
    public readonly string Hello;

    public string Hello2 { get; }
}
```

Both can only be set during the constructor and both offer readonly access outside of the class.. I'm a little tired so I might be missing something.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One reason would be for data binding - .net implements binding to properties but not to public fields.

Some discussion here : [Why can't we use public fields for data binding in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27582340/why-cant-we-use-public-fields-for-data-binding-in-c)

Answer (score 39):

Making it a property rather than a field means it can be used on interfaces.

The exact implementation (although auto-properties don't really have much implementation...) is also abstracted, so you could in the future base it on a combination of fields without breaking (compile) compatibility.

Comment: Great example thanks, I knew there was something obvious I was missing here. The context I was wondering about was the Startup.cs in the default asp.net core template, interestingly Startup doesn't implement an interface, but perhaps the property is used as a hook elsewhere.